# How to find out what attributes Rails has cached for a class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How do I figure out what attributes Rails has cached for a class?

I know when you do something like:
User.new for the first time, it retrieves the attributes for it from the database and caches it.

How can I programmatically find out what attributes it has cached in the current session (NOT what attributes are for the model in the db currently) ?

Comment: _`User.new` for the first time, it retrieves the attributes for it from the database_ - it doesn't retrieve attributes from database only intialize a new object.